# Counter between 2 values with Daily Reset

Tags: php, cron, counter

I need help creating a counter that starts from 1 value (2000000) and ends at 2nd value (2500000), resets every day and does not restart upon page load.

I was able to get almost exactly what I want with javascript - but this restarts on page load/refresh. I imagine I need to write this in PHP, but I can't figure out how - any help/pointers would be awesome.

Here is the javascript example [on JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vax5W/70/) and below:

```
var start = 200000001;
var end   = 250000000;
var interval = 578;

var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
 if(start <= end){
    $("#start").text(start++);
 }else{
    stop();   
 }
},interval);

function stop(){
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);    
}
```

Comment: you could tie the initial page load javascript function into an ajax call to the db that as an event running - the `event` updates a record every second. The return from the ajax function provides the current value of your counter, from there the javascript timeout kicks in ???

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to solve you problem with ajax function and get the value from a database.

if you want use Cronjob and php for your probelm and dont work with database , use text file .

save your current number in a text file , i write a function for you a sample below :

```
    function yourfunction($start,$end){
    $perv = file_get_contents("num.txt");
      if($perv <= $end){
        $current = $perv++;
        file_put_contents("num.txt","$current");
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you MOB, going to try it out and see if I can work it out. To be clear - this function above would be what runs on the cronjob? correct?